# What's a good swiss-army framework for the next 5 years?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, frameworks

Basically, we want to use no flash, and eschew php where possible (for marketing reasons).

Right now, I'm looking at Ruby on Rails and like what I see... but I'm not really a programmer, having working primarily with Wordpress, Drupal, and Joomla for the past 10 years.

Our sites need to have a lot of custom apps built into them (video uploading and galleries, user accounts, employee time logging, and more) with consistant looks. We don't expect to have any high-traffic sites (nothing in excess of 500 unique views in a day).

Anyone think that Rails is **Not** a good choice for the next 5 years or so?

Comment: So you want me to look into the future for you?  Don't you think I'd have better things to do than answer SO questions if I could look into the future?

Comment: You're not a programmer, you're evaluating frameworks (the programmer's job which you're not qualified to do), and you choose languages based on *marketing reasons*?  Congratulations--you're the exact stereotype of everything that's wrong with the industry.

Comment: @Glenn, I hope you don't own a Gun :P

Comment: "outlook not so good" : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/add-a-magic-8-ball-feature-to-the-ask-a-question-page :)

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to the 'marketing reasons' for not choosing php? As a marketing student and a hobbyist php developer I'm intrigued.

Comment: @Gollum I think I hope Glenn *does* have a gun :-)

Comment: For less than 1000000 page views over 5 years you'll need to look at development cost very closely. The cost per pageview is likely to be prohibitive

Answer (score 1):

[HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/)

While we can't predict the future, we could work in learning well the currently available technologies.

Comment: HTML5 rocks, but in no way does it influence the choice of a server-side language and framework (at least among ones that are sufficiently flexible to serve whatever HTML, JS and CSS they're given as "templates", rather than "synthesize" them as they go;-). None of the frameworks discussed in this Q and its As lacks that flexibility (except, I guess, Silverlight -- and possibly ASP.NET, I'm less familiar with that one).

Comment: @Alex Oh, that was for serverside too? mmhh make it HTML6 rocks then ;) How knows, iPhone 4 has more capacity than the first iMac 10 yrs ago.  10 yrs. ago, Java was struggling to be accepted as a mainstream platform.  Chrome didn't exist ( nor half of google products )  and Internet explorer... mmmhh nahh that haven't change too much :P

Answer (score 1):

I'd say python/Django over RoR.

If you weren't avoiding PHP, Zend would be a safe(ish) bet for the next 5 years (probably).

Mind you, you're by your own admission not a programmer and you're at least partially basing an engineering/technical decision on marketing (OMFG), so I'd be more worried about you lasting 5 years than any framework you choose...

Comment: I'm curious -- _why_ would you say python/Django over RoR?  They both seem to be very popular and technically solid -- so what's your _motivation_ for suggesting one over the other (rather than just making sure that the OP is aware of both)?

Comment: @Alex No single thing, after all it's a hunch more than anything concrete.  I'm more impressed with pythons technical & RE aspects, with RoR I always get a strong wiff of hype/fashion/fad ('Rails is a ghetto').  Twitter's frequent outages.  Why did Google choose python (along with Java) for their app engine platform? When $Big_Company choose a platform it's an indicator (not a guarantee obviously) that it's got a slightly better chance of lasting 18 months or longer, despite loads of people rushing off to the Next Big Thing.

Comment: thanks for clarifying.  BTW, when Google chose Python, Ruby did not exist yet (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560310/heavy-usage-of-python-at-google/2561008#2561008 -- my second most popular answer ever, BTW;-), and, while I'm sure we'd chose it again today, the reason I can be really sure is that so many prominent Pythonistas have been hired at Google over the course of the years since that language choice!-)

Answer (score 0):

Rails will still be around in 5 years. So will C# (.net), silverlight etc.  The Microsoft stack is too widely used to vanish.

Comment: @belisarius not like FoxPro (since it's not part of .NET Web stack). But since I just finished converting a FoxPro app to the Web and MVC/SqlServer, your comment made me laugh. :) FoxPro is awful.