# append in a list in Python using result value or a function

Tags: python, optimization, coding-style

are the both approaches equivalent from a point of view of performance and coding-style?

```
def foo(n):
    return n*2

# case 1 with ".append(function())"

mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
result = list()
for l in mylist:
    result.append(foo(l))

# case 2 ".append(result)"

mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
result = list()
for l in mylist:
    r = foo(l)
    result.append(r)
```

Comment: Solution 1 is more readable and compact but basically nobody cares.

Comment: performance `=` , coding `!=` first better, but Python supports much better ways..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approaches are more or less equivalent; option 2 does a *little* more work; it has to do an extra store and name lookup for the temporary variable. In practice, the difference is minimal and you should be focusing on code readability more than premature optimization.

For your *specific* example you'd be much better off using a list comprehension:

```
result = [foo(l) for l in mylist]
```

The list comprehension constructs the list in C code and does not have to look up the `.append()` method each loop iteration.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. My question was more theoretical than practice. Normally i use the first case.

Comment: Sorry for the extra question, but why C or C++ are more fast than other language as Python?

Comment: @Gianni: Because C and C++ can be compiled to machine code, having made very different decisions about code structure and rigidity of the type system. In the end, what are you more productive in, what makes you create solutions faster?

Comment: @Gianni: In that light, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2561008/100297) as to why Google uses Python is interesting.

Comment: For my work "scientific software" for analyzing data from satellite and Laser point (http://vimeo.com/16282938) Python is not fast but help me to write in a short time a prototype to analyzing the data.

Comment: Take a look at `numpy`, `scipy`, or `pandas`; all libraries that make specific analysis jobs much faster, while still giving you the power of Python to control it all.

Answer (score 2):

I think they are the same, but best option would be `map(foo, mylist)` - even from performance point of view as `append` can cause list resize which takes extra time

Comment: In python 3, `map()` would return an iterator; the list comprehension case can still outperform `list(map(..))` if you needed a list all along.

Comment: You are right with this point about Python 3. I think that performance difference between `list(imap(..))` and `map(..)` would be very hard to notice especially for list longer than some (not big) X. Also for Python 2.x advantage could be on `map` side

Comment: Yes, `map()` in Python 2 is *slightly* faster for the specific example inputs in the OP. With *long* lists, the list comprehension wins however, as it builds the result list more efficiently.

Comment: Are you sure about that list is built differently for list comprehension than from some iterable? Intuitively this should work  exactly the same way - that comprehension is transformed into generator which is base for new list...

Comment: The list comprehension does *not* use a generator, actually. Both `map()` and a list comprehension have dedicated C code to build lists. I used the `timeit` module to compare the performance of both approaches.

Answer (score 2):

You might have some performance gain in just removing the tempoarary assignment, but remember, premature optimization is evil, and micro-optimization is not worth the effort

Off course there are better ways to do, for example

**List Comprehension**

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
result = [n*2 for n in mylist]
```

Comment: Thanks Abhijit. Why "premature optimization is evil"? i read this sentence everywhere!!!

Comment: @Gianni You should be worrying about the clarity and robustness of the code first

Answer (score 1):

```
result = [foo(i) for i in mylist]
```

is what you want.